# Ansible: ecs_task check status

Tags: ansible, amazon-ecs

I have some AWS Fargate tasks executed by Ansible and I need to check task status

Is there a kind of `ecs_task_info` module?

Comment: It [does not appear so](https://galaxy.ansible.com/search?deprecated=false&keywords=ecs_task&order_by=-relevance&page=1), so I'd guess you'll have to use `command: aws ecs ...`, or consider whether [`ecs_service_info:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/aws/ecs_service_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-aws-ecs-service-info-module) will do what you want

Comment: I don't have service, I run just a task, so aws cli seems to be the only way